# Android studio 2.1.1 app taking too much time to launch app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

hi i have updated android studio to 2.1.1 now my app is taking too much time to load all-most 10-15 sec extra. but same code was working properly in old version ..

is any way i can revert my android studio

does any one facing this issue ?

my luncher activity code :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(this, hActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }          
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: why the 20 seconds delay there ?

Comment: 2 sec as i want to show image for 2 sec

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to revert your android studio version,
But in case that you didn't do this:

Go to settings and check the offline mode option in gradle section.

This should make your app build and run faster because of skipping internet connections for gradle build every time you run your code.

Comment: i am talking about app on device

Comment: if i remove application class it working properly why it so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate `Instant Run`:

Preferences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

**Update:**

You can try also downgrading `Gradle` version in your project `Build.gradle` from:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'`

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1'
```